# Is it possible to rig an STL file?

Tags: rigging, armature

Is it possible to rig an armature to an STL file?

I have been trying and it's not seeming to have it. I'm a bit of an amateur, bit it's still not seeming to have it.

Thank you, 
Harry

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to rig an STL file.

Firstly, Blender cannot open STL files. They can only be imported to Blender and once imported the information contained in such files is translated to a format native to Blender and, so to speak, become a .blend file.

Secondly, the term 'rigging' in CG context does not apply to files or file formats and saying to rig a file format makes no sense at all. Rigging is a process of making some kind of deformation or control system to make it easier to animate objects in animation software packages like Blender. So if you want to rig a 3d model that you imported from an  STL file to Blender, then it's exactly the same as to rig any other model in Blender. Rigging however is a very complex and wide subject and cannot be described in full in one answer. You will need to ask a more specific question and provide the full context of your situation to get any meaningful help.

Comment: Yes, yes. So once I have opened an STL file, imported it into Blender and it has been converted, is it possible to then go about rigging this? I do understand what I meant did come across a bit stupid, but essentially you got the gist of it.    So I'm trying to add a armature to the object, is it possible to attach this armature, or because it has been converted from an STL files does it mean it won't allow me? Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply, Harry

Comment: I understand what you want to learn. I am sure pretty much everyone reading the question here does. It's just that I don't think it is possible to answer that with a single answer. The subject just seems to be too broad to explain in a single answer in full. You either need to narrow down the question or learn a lot more information than can be provided in an answer. Maybe watch a few tutorials about rigging and then ask more specific questions about what you struggle with while learning rigging.

Comment: Also please try to communicate what you mean clearly. Your question text does not convey any information at all. It's often better to tell it in simple language instead of using terminology incorrectly. For example: "I have a model of [the thing you have] in STL format. I want to animate it so it could [do whatever you want it to do in the animation], because [your purpose of the animation]. I think I need to rig it so it I could easily animate [the movements you need in your animation]. How could I go about it? " I think that would get answers or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for replying Martynas, I really appreciate it. I do apologise about my question being very vague, I agree that this won't help myself or other members of this community.  However, I was just looking to see if members of the community have had success with rigging imported STL files, rather than how to achieve this. Because I'm new to blender I wanted to know if I was wasting my time or not, rather than expecting someone to write an A-to-B process of achieving this.

Comment: Would you be able to help finalise an answer for me, about, "Is it possible to successfully parent an armature to an imported STL file?" Once again, thanks for responding and slapping me up to scratch with my good practice with asking questions here.

Comment: It is possible to store 3d models that can be rigged in STL format and rigging is possible in Blender because it has a lot of functionality suitable for that. It is also possible to store poor quality 3d models with very bad topology in STL format that will give you terrible results if you attempt to rig them in certain ways.